tracing bridge selection in micrometer
Background:
Our system contains 40+ micro-services (spring-boot 3.2.x), they are all deployed on a Kubernetes cluster, logs are printed in the pods, and we use ELK stack (LogStash, ElasticSearch, Kibana) to search, analyze, and visualize logs.
by default the log details don't contains the trace_id & span_id, which causes difficulties to search a particular request, especially in production environment.
so my requirement is only to add trace_id & span_id into the log.
Confuses:
after some researching, I found the micrometer tracking maybe good for me.
but I got stuck on the selection for the tracking bridge, since micrometer support brave and otel,
I tried both bridge in my local, both meet my requirement.
I don't know the internal mechanism for the bridge, I am just worried that include the bridge is a little bit heavy for my scenario? since I don't need other functionalities apart from logging.
any micrometer expert can help on this?
Thanks in advance.

If you are on Boot 3.2, and you add actuator, you only need to add a tracing bridge to have log correlation out of the box (traceId+spanId in the logs). Usually we recommend starting using the Brave bridge if you don't have any special needs for OTel since OTel still have unstable parts while Brave is a more mature project.
